# Can we achieve polymorphism through const function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Can we achieve polymorphism through const function?
I mean does a function a() and another function a()const behave polymorphically?

```
void func(int a){}
void func(int a)const {}
```

Comment: No, they must have the same signature.

Comment: That depends what you mean by polymorphism. Overloading, or [Ad hoc polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism), is a type of polymorphism. However when people talk about polymorphism in C++ they usually mean dynamic dispatch via virtual functions (also known as [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)), which this is not.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by polymorphism, because the answer could go either way.

Comment: Needs to be virtual for polymorphism. You can check if this is the case using the override keyword in C++11

Comment: @JustinMeiners needs to be virtual for *virtual* or runtime polymorphism. But there are more types of polymorphism. Function overloading provides another means for polymorphism.

Comment: @juanchopanza How in C++ could a method be called polymorphicaly without virtual? (genuine question not smart ass)

Comment: @juanchopanza ah I now see from your edit what your talking about

Comment: @JustinMeiners Compile time polymorphism: `void foo(int)`, `void foo(std::string)`. Or, following the example above, `void foo(someType&)`, `void foo(const someType&)`.

Comment: [What is compile-time polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881468/c-what-is-compile-time-polymorphism-and-why-does-it-only-apply-to-functions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is . you can overload it !!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
protected:
    int x;
public:
    Test (int i):x(i) { }
    void fun() const
    {
        cout << "fun() const called " << endl;
    }
    void fun()
    {
        cout << "fun() called " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1 (10);
    const Test t2 (20);
    t1.fun();
    t2.fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: The above program compiles and runs fine, and produces following output.

```
fun() called
fun() const called
```

The two methods ‘void fun() const’ and ‘void fun()’ have same signature except that one is const and other is not. Also, if we take a closer look at the output, we observe that, ‘const void fun()’ is called on const object and ‘void fun()’ is called on non-const object.
C++ allows member methods to be overloaded on the basis of const type. Overloading on the basis of const type can be useful when a function return reference or pointer. We can make one function const, that returns a const reference or const pointer, other non-const function, that returns non-const reference or pointer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not polymorphism.  This is function overloading.

You might be confusing *overloading* with *overriding*.

Function **overloads** are two functions that have the same name, but different signatures.  The code you've posted is an example.  The parts of a function that make up the signature include the parameter list and the `const` qualification of the method.  Notably, the function's return type is *not* part of the function's signature.

Function **overrides** are created using the keyword `virtual`.  The have the same name and the same* signature.  The basic idea behind overrides is to be able to call a derived class' special functions if all you have is the pointer to the base class.  Here's an example:

```
class Foo
{
public: 
  virtual std::string GetIt() const { return "FOO" }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  std::string GetIt() const { return "BAR"; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo* that = new Bar;
  cout << that->GetIt();
}
```

The program will output "BAR", even though the pointer is a pointer to a `Foo`.

---

*"the same signature":  Actually, co-variant signatures.

Comment: Function overloading is a type of polymorphism.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Perhaps in an academic sense, but the Standard is quite clear what "polymorphism" means in C++:  **10.3 Virtual Functions** *1/Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming. A class that declares or
inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.*

Comment: A class that inherits a virtual function _is_ a polymorphic class.  Does the Standard also imply that overloading/templates are _not_ polymorphic?

Comment: @MooingDuck: The standard doesn't say that overloads & templates *are* polymorphic.  Hence they aren't according to the Standard, in much the same way that `std::vector` is not part of the STL.

Comment: So maybe there are "polymorphic classes", but the term "polymorphic" isn't restricted to that. There are also *polymorphic function wrappers* in §20.8.11.

Comment: I am bit confused here, what I know is that overloading are compile time polymorphism and overriding  is runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

As @chris explained, "No, they must have the same signature".

Answer (score 0):

**Yes we can achieve polymorphic behavior**.

As we can able to call those functions, one(*const function*) with constant object and 
the other(*non constant function*) with non constant object. Both the functions have same name but they are of different usage nd polymorphism also refers to **same name but different forms**.