# How this opencv function explained in c++

Tags: c++, function, opencv

i do really need to understand how thing works on this function in particular, maybe in all functions too in general from docs. here is from the docs of the function in opencv : and this is just one of them.

`int cv::createTrackbar (const String & trackbarname, const String & winname,
int * value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange = 0,void * userdata = 0)`

and here is a code that someone wrote that works :

`createTrackbar("H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar);`
`createTrackbar("H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar);`
`createTrackbar("S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar);`
`createTrackbar("S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar);`
`createTrackbar("V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar);`
`createTrackbar("V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar);`

now my question is :

1. there are 6 arguments, why that guy write only 5 arguments ?
2. the docs says `int` at first, why `createTrackbar` does not have int ?
3. what does `&` mean in `const String & trackbarname` , i can understand that   `"H_MIN"` is a const string and it is a trackbarname, but what is `&` mean, and why not write `&` also in that code ?
4. same question also in `const String & winname`, that is `&` mean ?
5. in third arguments `int * value` , value pointer to an int, and declared in  global variable, why so complicated to written ? can't we just write int `H_MIN = 0` (if i'm right about this), `H_MAX = 256` ?
6. on fourth argument `int count` , where is that code exactly ?
7. fifth argument, `TrackbarCallback onChange = 0` , i dont understand this
8. last argument, `void * userdata = 0` he write a function called `on_trackbar`  which only this : `void on_trackbar(int, void*){}` i dont understand this either

sorry for too much to ask, i just need really to understand how i'm gonna write a function from docs correctly or custom.

and here are all the code :

```
//objectTrackingTutorial.cpp

//Written by  Kyle Hounslow 2013

//Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")
//, to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, 
//and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

//The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

//THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER 
//LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
//IN THE SOFTWARE.

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
//initial min and max HSV filter values.
//these will be changed using trackbars
int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 256;
int S_MIN = 0;
int S_MAX = 256;
int V_MIN = 0;
int V_MAX = 256;
//default capture width and height
const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;
//max number of objects to be detected in frame
const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS = 50;
//minimum and maximum object area
const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20 * 20;
const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH / 1.5;
//names that will appear at the top of each window
const string windowName = "Original Image";
const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";
void on_trackbar(int, void*)
{//This function gets called whenever a
    // trackbar position is changed





}
string intToString(int number){


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
void createTrackbars(){
    //create window for trackbars


    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName, 0);
    //create memory to store trackbar name on window
    char TrackbarName[50];
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
    sprintf_s(TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX);
    //create trackbars and insert them into window
    //3 parameters are: the address of the variable that is changing when the trackbar is moved(eg.H_LOW),
    //the max value the trackbar can move (eg. H_HIGH), 
    //and the function that is called whenever the trackbar is moved(eg. on_trackbar)
    //                                  ---->    ---->     ---->      
    createTrackbar("H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar);

}
void drawObject(int x, int y, Mat &frame){

    //use some of the openCV drawing functions to draw crosshairs
    //on your tracked image!

    //UPDATE:JUNE 18TH, 2013
    //added 'if' and 'else' statements to prevent
    //memory errors from writing off the screen (ie. (-25,-25) is not within the window!)

    circle(frame, Point(x, y), 20, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (y - 25>0)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, y - 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (y + 25<FRAME_HEIGHT)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, y + 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, FRAME_HEIGHT), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (x - 25>0)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x - 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(0, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (x + 25<FRAME_WIDTH)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x + 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(FRAME_WIDTH, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    putText(frame, intToString(x) + "," + intToString(y), Point(x, y + 30), 1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

}
void morphOps(Mat &thresh){

    //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
    //the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle

    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3));
    //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8, 8));

    erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);
    erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);


    dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);
    dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);



}
void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed){

    Mat temp;
    threshold.copyTo(temp);
    //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    //use moments method to find our filtered object
    double refArea = 0;
    bool objectFound = false;
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
        int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
        if (numObjects<10){
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

                Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                double area = moment.m00;

                //if the area is less than 20 px by 20px then it is probably just noise
                //if the area is the same as the 3/2 of the image size, probably just a bad filter
                //we only want the object with the largest area so we safe a reference area each
                //iteration and compare it to the area in the next iteration.
                if (area>400 && area<FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH/1.5 && area>refArea){
                    printf("%f \n", area);
                    x = moment.m10 / area;
                    y = moment.m01 / area;
                    objectFound = true;
                    refArea = area;
                }
                else objectFound = false;


            }
            //let user know you found an object
            if (objectFound == true){
                putText(cameraFeed, "Tracking Object", Point(0, 50), 2, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                //draw object location on screen
                drawObject(x, y, cameraFeed);
            }

        }
        else putText(cameraFeed, "TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER", Point(0, 50), 1, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //some boolean variables for different functionality within this
    //program
    bool trackObjects = true;
    bool useMorphOps = true;
    //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
    Mat cameraFeed;
    //matrix storage for HSV image
    Mat HSV;
    //matrix storage for binary threshold image
    Mat threshold;
    //x and y values for the location of the object
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    //create slider bars for HSV filtering
    createTrackbars();
    //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
    VideoCapture capture;
    //open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)
    capture.open(0);
    //set height and width of capture frame
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
    //all of our operations will be performed within this loop
    while (1){
        //store image to matrix
        capture.read(cameraFeed);
        //convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
        cvtColor(cameraFeed, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        //filter HSV image between values and store filtered image to
        //threshold matrix
        inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), threshold);
        //perform morphological operations on thresholded image to eliminate noise
        //and emphasize the filtered object(s)
        if (useMorphOps)
            morphOps(threshold);
        //pass in thresholded frame to our object tracking function
        //this function will return the x and y coordinates of the
        //filtered object
        if (trackObjects)
            trackFilteredObject(x, y, threshold, cameraFeed);

        //show frames 
        imshow(windowName2, threshold);
        imshow(windowName, cameraFeed);
        imshow(windowName1, HSV);


        //delay 30ms so that screen can refresh.
        //image will not appear without this waitKey() command
        waitKey(30);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *there are 6 arguments, why that guy write only 5 arguments* -- The function has defaulted the last two arguments.  This is C++ basics.  Some of your other questions also deal with the basics of C++ -- maybe you should invest some time in books and/or tutorials on C++?

Comment: "what does & mean" & means to pass a variable by reference instead of copying it. That way the calling variable ca be changed in the function. If a const variable is passed by reference this is typically done for performance reasons since copying values needs some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

1)The last argument, userdata, is defaulted, which is seen by the =0 in the function signature. This means that if you don't specify a value for the argument, it will be set to the default value of 0.

2) createTrackbar has  return type of int, however, you are disregarding this data by not setting createTrackbar to a variable, which is fine in your case.

3)The & shows a pass by reference. This means that the variable that you are passing the function can be modified during the function. See *[here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)* for more information on this.

4)Same as above

5)This does not have to be global necessarily. What is happening here is that you are passing the memory address of an integer to the function. This will allow the function to de-reference what is at that memory address. If you are not familiar with how c and c++ deal with pointers/reference/memory, you should consider doing some research on it, as it is a very integral concept to c programming. A good place to start is [*here*](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html). In terms of what this variable does, essentially, it is the address of a variable that you can reference that updates with the position of the slider, so that you don't need to call the slider function every time if you are only grabbing the value from the slider.

6) Count is the max position on the slider. This is clear in the documentation.

7) This onchange method is the callback to a function that can be executed whenever the trackbar position changes. It is defaulted to 0, meaning that if you don't specify a function to be called when the trackbar moves, then no function will be called. If you are simply trying to get the value of the trackbar, see what I wrote for point 5 and use the value argument instead.

8)This is not the userdata argument. The compiler is able to see that the on_trackbar is actually the argument for onchange due to its type. Thus, he is actually defaulting the userdata to 0, and has a function when the trackbar moves. For more information on this, you should read up on compiler time polymorphism in c. Great post about it [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881468/c-what-is-compile-time-polymorphism-and-why-does-it-only-apply-to-functions)

Looks like you don't quite have a solid handle on your C and C++ basics yet. I would recommend working through a book on C or C++, as there is some really powerful stuff that you can do with some of the concepts you talked about. Best of luck!